# Finding the general solution to system of linear equations: $y' = 2y,y''=4y-y'$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:** I want to find the general solution to the following system:
>   $\begin{pmatrix} \dot{y}_1 \\ \dot{y}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0\\4&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$

I find working in questions makes them look cluttered and noone helps. They are hidden below.

> I believe I am meant to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors here. Since we have a zero on the opposite diagonal, we know that the eigenvalues are $2$ and $-1$, and the eigenvectors corresponding to these turned out to be $(3,4)^T$ and $(0,\gamma)^T$.

cont.

> I am fairly sure I am meant to use the form $\vec{y}= \alpha \vec{x}^{(1)} e^{\lambda_1 t} + \beta \vec{x}^{(2)} e^{\lambda_2 t}$

*Attempt solution*

> Hence it should equal $\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} e^{2t}+  \beta \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix} e^{-t} $, but I am not sure this is right.

Comment: If you are not sure, there is a way to check it: insert your solution into the equation and see if it holds (and you should find that that is indeed the case)! btw you are free to normalize the eigenvectors (the normalization is anyway taken care of by $\alpha$ and $\beta$) so you can put $\gamma=1$ without any loss of generality.

Comment: @Thursday: What is written in the problem title does not match what is in the body of the problem. Is that just a typo in the title? Your solution is correct, but Winther gave great advice on normalizing by setting value to $1$, which you should do.